# Getting value of key from Web Content Display Portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-6.2

I got a requirement. I have added two text fields `Value` and `Key` from structure in Web Content Display portlet.
[image: Web Content with two fields 'Key' and 'Value']

right now in the portlet i am getting value from hard code like below.

```
BasicModel model = (BasicModel)requestContext.getFlowScope().get("BasicModel");
        if(model == null){
            model = new BasicModel();
        }
        model.setEmployeeId("AB1223344S");
        model.setHireDate("01-Jan-2000");
        model.setNiNumber("AB123456S");
        model.setDateOfBirth("12-Dec-1980");
        model.setBasicForm(new BasicDetailsForm());
    }
```

but what i want is to get the `value` of each `attribute` from `web content`. Like, If i have given `lfr.intel.empid` as `key` and `ABSD1822D` as value in the added web content structure field like this. 
[image: new added information for key and value]

and we can fetch the value of key like this.

```
model.setEmployeeId(lfr.intel.empid);
```

Comment: Why you are using we content here?  Would you elaborate your requirement in detail

Comment: @PankajkumarKathiriya if i could i would kind of requirement from seniors.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom function for this which passes the key to that function, now that function will use the JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil API to get respective value from the DB.

Now you need to find How to fetch values from JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil, which you can google or [this](http://liferayiseasy.blogspot.in/2015/08/get-web-contentjournal-article-fields.html) link can help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Do we have to add any property in my portal-ext.properties file?

Comment: No.
BDW why to add entry in properties file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming that you could get the `JournalArticle` object, I've done it using the `resourcePrimKey`

```
long resourcePrimKey = 12345; //hard coded the resourcePrimKey
JournalArticle article = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getLatestArticle(resourcePrimKey);
com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.Document document = SAXReaderUtil.read(article.getContentByLocale("en_US"));

Node keyNode = document.selectSingleNode("/root/dynamic-element[@name='Key']/dynamic-content");
String key = keyNode.getStringValue();

Node valueNode = document.selectSingleNode("/root/dynamic-element[@name='Value']/dynamic-content");
String value = valueNode .getStringValue();
```